# How do you decide how the aliyos should be arranged when there are not sufficient yisroelim in a minyan?

Tags: halacha, kohen-priest, torah-service, levites-leviyim

*(This is a question based on an event. A shaaloh was asked. The object of the question is to examine the underlying reasons for the dinim in the situation.)*

A family minyan meeting once only on Shabbos day, consists mainly of Kohanim and Leviim. There are enough others to give the following aliyos to the Torah: Kohen, Levi, Yisroel, Yisroel, Yisroel, Yisroel but there is no other Yisroel to make up the seven. There is a Levi for Maftir.

What are the factors that govern how the aliyos should be arranged?

Obviously the seventh must be a Kohen or Levi. Is it permitted to call him last?

Comment: If I recall correctly, the whole premise of Kohen->Levi->Yisrael ... was to minimize fights in normal circumstances. In an odd case like this, I think I'd heard you would do: Kohen, Levi, Yisrael, Kohen, Levi, Yisrael, Kohen [shvii], then whoever for Maftir. Assuming you have the right "manpower" for that lineup.

Comment: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_40543_8.pdf

Comment: ואם יש שם ב׳ לויים או יותר ע ד ז׳ והשאר כהנים יקרא כהן ת חלה ואח״כ לוי וכן תמיד מפסיק לוי עד שכלו הלוים קורין הכהנים זא״ז (שע׳׳ש),

Comment: עיר שכולה לויים וששה ישראלים קורא לוי תחלה ואח״כ כל הישראלים זא״ז, ואי ליכא ששה ישראלים או שיש ב׳ ישראלים קורין לוי ואח״כ הישראלים כולם אם אין גדול ממנו בישראלים ואח״כ הלוים, ואי ליכא רק ישראל א חד יקרא הוא תחלה ואח״כ הלוים זא״ז (שע״ש

Comment: Kohen, then Levi then Yisrael then anyone you want. It should normally be all Yisraelim if there are enough to go around. In this case there are not so you must call up someone else for one of the last 4 (but the 3rd aliya must be a Yisrael).

Comment: @cham  I asked **What are the factors that govern how the aliyos should be arranged?** not "what should we do?"

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok within this context, aren't the 2 questions the same? The *factors that govern* the arrangement would tell you what the arrangement should be, by inference, no? It seems that the content of the question already tells you the factors that require rearrangement. Did I miss some nuance?

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok "How do you decide how.." gives an answer that implies what action to take. As in, "I have to get from point A to B. I have 2 routes, How do I decide which route to take? Answer: You take the route with the least traffic." That's both HOW you decide as well as what to do! Seems that cham's comment includes the factors, as well.

Comment: The question in plain language is there are less than five @AvrohomYitzchok   yisroelim. How does one share out the aliyot. Why is it obvious the seventh is a cohen or levi? Who says you first call up all the yisroelim?

Comment: My answer seems to say @AvrohomYitzchok that you first call up all the yisroelim although by no means obvious to me. So that is the answer. You first call up the cohen levi then all the yisoelim then cohen levi, cohen levi etc.

Comment: http://www.hakirah.org/Vol23Broyde.pdf

Answer (score 1):

A Kohen or Levi could be called to any of the later aliyot (but not the 3rd one).

One should also generally avoid calling up 2 kohanim or 2 levi'im in a row, as this may appear to question the lineage of the first one.

See the Shulchan Orech:

https://shulchanaruch.wordpress.com/187-2/

Comment: Perhaps my question, here, seems "trivial". Why can't you "recycle" one of the previous Yisra'elim? Is there any halacha that prevents a Yisra'el getting 2 consecutive aliyot or say, the shlishi getting shvi'i also?

Comment: yes one doesnt give @DanF give two aliyot unless from a different sefer.

Comment: @cham I didn't know this rule. Is this listed in the same area in SA as in Cashcow's link, or do you have another source for this?

Comment: @cham and the double kohen when there's no levi is an exception I presume?

Comment: @andrewmh20 yes actually. See the shulchan aruch mentioned above and mishna berurah there. I remember a similar story happened to me and my family. We are all Leviim, we made a davening at home and didnt have enough "commonfolk" around. A shayla was asked and we were told to restart the order again. So it worked out like this (we had 3 yisroelim) kohen, levi, yisroel, yisroel, kohen, levi, yisroel. And for maftir anyone can go